# Understanding numpy.linalg.norm() in IPython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ipython

I'm creating a linear regression model for supervised learning.

I have a bunch of data points plotted on a graph (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), etc, where the x's are the real data and the y values are the training data values.

As part of the next step in writing a basic nearest neighbor algorithm, I want to create a distance metric to measure the distance (and similarity) between two instances.

If I wanted to write a generic function to compute the L-Norm distance in ipython, I know that a lot of people use numpy.linalg.norm(arr, ord = , axis=). What I'm confused about is how to format my array of data points so that it properly calculates the L-norm values.

If I had just two data points, say (3, 4) and (5, 9), would my array need to look like this with each data point's values in one row?

```
arry = ([[3,4] 
         [5,9]])
```

or would it need to look like this where all the x-axis values are in one row and y in another?

```
arry = ([[3,5]
         [4,9]])
```

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the docstring for `norm` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)?  The last few examples show the use of the `axis` argument.

Answer (score 12):

`numpy.linalg.norm(x) == numpy.linalg.norm(x.T)` where `.T` denotes the transpose.  So it doesn't matter.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.rand(5000, 2)
>>> x.shape
(5000, 2)
>>> x.T.shape
(2, 5000)
>>> np.linalg.norm(x)
57.82467111195578
>>> np.linalg.norm(x.T)
57.82467111195578
```

Edit:

Given that your vector is basically

```
x = [[real_1, training_1],
     [real_2, training_2],
      ...
     [real_n, training_n]]
```

then the Frobenius norm is basically computing

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2))
```

Are you sure this is the right metric.  There are a whole bunch of other norms.  Here are 3

```
np.sum((x[:,0]**2 - x[:,1]**2) # N-dimensional euclidean norm
np.sqrt(np.sum(x[:,0]**2) + np.sum(x[:,1]**2)) # L^2 norm
np.sqrt(x[:,0].dot(x[:,1])) # sqrt dot product
```

Comment: does the axis feature matter? from the reference documentation, it says that it takes either int, 2-tuples of ints, none, etc. If I have a 2D graph (x, y) points versus say a 3D graph with (x,y,z) do I need to specify the axis or can I just leave it?

Comment: If you have a 2D graph, leave it.  But overall, are you sure the L2 norm is the appropriate measure for you.  Don't you want to compute the similarity between vector x = (x1, x2, ..., xn) and vector y = (y1, y2, ..., yn)?  Maybe something like sum((x1-y1)**2 + (x2-y2)**2 + ... + (xn-yn)**2) would be more appropriate?

Comment: yeah, I had looked at that, but I was under the assumption that the np.linalg.norm was a shortcut function to calculating the different p-norms. Is that not correct? The problem I'm working on asks you to leave L as a variable, leaving room to potentially change what type of norm you want to calculate (L2 norm or euclidean norm or sqrt dot product, etc) based on what value you give it.